# How to load MrSID raster layer in QGIS on Mac OS?

Tags: qgis, mac, mrsid

I have just upgraded QGIS to 2.0 and now I can't load my SID raster layers.  I now remember that getting them into 1.8 was a performance but I can't remember all the details.

I have downloaded the latest SDK from Lizard -- I can remember that much and spent some time with google to try and figure out what to do next but I can't even find the 1.8 instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a Mac and QGIS from KyngChaos, then download the MrSID plugin of [KyngChaos: Framewoks](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks)

[image]

Comment: Doesn't appear to exist anymore...

Comment: If you want GDAL 1.10, go to  [KyngChaos: Unix Port Download Archive](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/archive)

Comment: The KnygChaos framework now contains a MrSid plugin for the current GDAL 1.11. You need the Lizardtech SDK as mentioned in the text.

Answer (score 2):

You should install QGIS with the [OSGeo4W Installer](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/).
In the installer, click advanced install, click next .. next.. and when you arrive at the select packages window, expand the libs tree and select the gdal-mrsid lib, click next and QGIS will install with mrsid suppport. That's it!

Comment: Sorry, one vital bit of info I forgot.  I am working on a Mac.  All the stuff I turned up with google referred to OSGeo4W