# Adding MrSid to QGIS on Windows

Tags: qgis, windows, mrsid

I'm fairly new to QGIS and was hoping someone could help me load some MrSID photos into QGIS.

I have read some posts and have installed the OSGEO4W Installer and selected the GDAL-MRSID Lib.

I also have the GDAL plugin installed.

However, after it installed I rebooted but have the same result.

I know the .sid file is good because I can load it into MapWindow without any issues.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73959/qgis-2-0-how-to-load-mrsid-raster-layer

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a case of QGIS not communicating with the correct GDAL version. You should also  install QGIS through the OSGEO4W installer as well. Then run QGIS from:

C:\OSGeo4W\bin\qgis.bat