# Can I use .aux, .sid, .sid.xml, .sid.aux.xml, or .sdw files as raster in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

I am working with data from my boss who uses ArcGIS. I am aware that .aux files accompany raster files, but to my knowledge you can still use .aux files to create rasters in ArcGIS.

I'm working with limited data. Is there a way to use any of these files to create a visible raster in QGIS? I'm getting a visual when I upload the .aux file to QGIS, but it's only a black image. If I fiddle with the style it will disappear and turn into a white image.

Also, my companion was able to make the .sid file work in her QGIS, but she uses a PC and I use a MAC. Would there be any explanation for this?

Comment: The SID file is the compressed raster in [MrSID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MrSID) format. It sounds like your build of QGIS (and likely the underlying GDAL build) doesn't have support for MrSID. A quick search about that yielded this question: [How to load MrSID raster layer in QGIS on Mac OS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73959/how-to-load-mrsid-raster-layer-in-qgis-on-mac-os)

Comment: @EvilGenius thanks for the link. I have downloaded the GDAL plug in package that includes MrSID, but i'm very unfamiliar with the plugin.

Answer (score 3):

.aux files are metadata files. There don't contain the actual raster data. Just "Add Raster" in QGIS and select the .sid file. If it doesn't load, you might need to check witht the advanced setup tool if the MrSID library has correctly been installed. See below the name of the library to install via the setup tool.

In my case, it's not installed, for example. I need to click on "Skip" once to switch to a number to be able to install it.

[image: MrSID GDAL format]

[image: MrSID GDAL format install]

Answer (score 0):

it works fine with QGIS 2.8. Just start a new project and go to "add layer" => "add raster layer" and load both .sid and .aux. The drop-down should be set to "all files *.* when browsing to find your file. Make sure that the sid image is the first layer to be added to your project, so you get the right CRS from the beginning to display your image.